# Delete video from Cloudinary not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

I can delete the images from [Cloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel), but the videos are not deleted.

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if ($request->has('video')) {
        $file = $request->file('video');
        $result = $file->storeOnCloudinary('Blog');
        $uploadedFileUrl = $result->getSecurePath();
        $uploadedFileId = $result->getPublicId();

        if (isset($post->imageFileId)) {
            Cloudinary::destroy($post->imageFileId);
        }
        if (isset($post->videoFileId)) {
            Cloudinary::destroy($post->videoFileId);
        }

        $update = [
            'video' => $uploadedFileUrl,
            'videoFileId' => $uploadedFileId,
            'image' => null,
            'imageFileId' => null,
        ];

        $post->update($update);
    }
}
```

Comment: if( isset($post->videoFileId)){
       Cloudinary::destroy($post->videoFileId);
    }

Comment: You will need to specify the `resource_type` and set it to `video` when deleting videos, otherwise, it defaults to `image` as mentioned [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_optional_parameters). You may need to do the same with the `type` parameter if the asset is `private` or `authenticated`

Comment: @LoicVdB thanks, it worked I changed it to                     
     Cloudinary::destroy($post->videoFileId, ["resource_type" => "video"]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add resource_type
Cloudinary::destroy($post->videoFileId, ["resource_type" => "video"]);

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if ($request->has('video')) {
        $file = $request->file('video');
        $result = $file->storeOnCloudinary('Blog');
        $uploadedFileUrl = $result->getSecurePath();
        $uploadedFileId = $result->getPublicId();

        if (isset($post->imageFileId)) {
            Cloudinary::destroy($post->imageFileId);
        }
        if (isset($post->videoFileId)) {
            Cloudinary::destroy($post->videoFileId, ["resource_type" => "video"]);
        }

        $update = [
            'video' => $uploadedFileUrl,
            'videoFileId' => $uploadedFileId,
            'image' => null,
            'imageFileId' => null,
        ];

        $post->update($update);
    }
}
```